# How efficient are java 11 java.net.http.Websocket comparing to undertow or vert.x, netty

Tags: java, websocket, vert.x, undertow

I can't find performance benchmark of java 11 client/server websockets comparing to undertow, jetty, vert.x. Is there any benchmark test out there and i just missed it or there is no such benchmark (which would be quite strange)?

Answer (score 2):

For majority of application Vert.x websockets are performant enough. Also benchmark results tend not to carry over to different domains i.e. you will see different results since your application is different than the benchmark application.

Nonetheless to your question - here are two links that will give some information around performance

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330298316_Performance_Comparison_and_Evaluation_of_WebSocket_Frameworks_Netty_Undertow_Vertx_Grizzly_and_Jetty

https://colobu.com/2015/05/22/implement-C1000K-servers-by-spray-netty-undertow-and-node-js/#comments [Google translate needed]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I saw the first research but I am more interested in performance of java.net.http.Websocket comparing to undertow, netty, etc ...
I am mostly using undertow, and it is great but I always rather use jdk then external libraries. I guess I will just go with it and see how it goes